# Which environment is it referring to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-sam, aws-toolkit

My version of vscode is 1.69.0 and my version of sam is 1.53.0. I have this error here and just wanted to know which environment is being referred to?

```
2022-08-01 14:38:50 [INFO]: Preparing to debug locally: Lambda ""
2022-08-01 14:38:50 [INFO]: Building SAM application...
2022-08-01 14:38:50 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/usr/local/bin/sam build --build-dir /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkG9KjVg/output --template /Users/user/directory/repository/file.yaml]
2022-08-01 14:38:52 [INFO]: Building codeuri: /Users/user/directory/repository/src/folder runtime: dotnet6 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: xfer

2022-08-01 14:38:52 [INFO]: 
Build Failed

2022-08-01 14:38:52 [INFO]: Error: DotnetCliPackageBuilder:Resolver - No dotnet cli executable found!

2022-08-01 14:38:52 [WARN]: "sam build" failed: /Users/user/directory/repository/file.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to run the following to symlink it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `sam build` step is performed on the local (host) machine, not in the Docker container.

If you set the `containerBuild` option (see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps-run-debug-config-ref.html)), then the `sam build` step is performed in the Docker container.